# SonicWall TZ205 Route traffic back to WAN IP

Tags: router, nat, local-area-network, sonicwall, wide-area-network

I have a customer who wants to be able to use the same configuration for an app whether he is at home or on the road. I have the port forward set up through the wizard and that works fine from external IPs, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to allow him to hit WANIP:PORT from his LAN and have it still route to the local device on this SonicWALL. If someone can point me in the right direction to get this set up without breaking anything else that would much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "forward rule", as a incoming NAT rule on the firewall, you need to tick the "Create a reflexible rule". That will create a loopback NAT rule.

That loopback rule detect your app want to talk to the public ip on that port, and it will translate the destination IP to stay inside your LAN, to prevent routing error

Comment: Yeah, in doing a bit more digging this morning I realized that there was already a Loopback rule that the vendor put in but it appears it was pointing at 'Firewalled Subnets' which is a default Address Group and for some reason only includes the 'primary lan subnet' and literally nothing else.  So I'm pretty sure that was the cause of my problem but your answer is correct as well :)

Comment: @SamK yes, its the problem with such rule, it create it when you first create the nat rule, but it doesnt update later if a change is done on the first rule